# Power series of a complex function with singularity point

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm taking a introdutory course on complex analysis and after seeing theorems of Taylor and Laurent series for complex functions I got to the exercises and found this one that I'm struggling to understand what is actually asked:

> Develop the function $z^{-1}$ in powers of $(z-1)$. Then obtain by derivation the developing of $z^{-2}$ in powers of $(z-1)$. Give the region of validity.

My thoughts were: I must write the Taylor series of $z^{-1}$ around $z_0 = 1$, then the region where the series converge are the interior of the circle $|z-1| = 1$. Then I'm allowed to derivate inside this region and get the representation of $z^{-2}$ in powers of $(z-1)$, and the region of validity will be the disk $|z-1| < 1$.

But thinking on Laurent series, I think I can actually write the same expression and the region where the series representation holds will be any annular region $1 < |z-1| < \infty$.

So the answer for the region of validity of the power series representation will be the union of these two regions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The opposite, actually. There are two different Laurent series for $z^{-1}$ around $z=1$: one of them is the Taylor series, valid for $|z-1|<1$, and the other is a Laurent series with $(z-1)^{-k}$ terms, valid for $1<|z-1|$.

Comment: ${1 \over z} = {1 \over 1-(z-1)} = 1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2+...$.